# Multiple hashtags on Instagram API

Tags: php, api, instagram

class.php and I am trying to get the instagram feed but with multiple hashtags. My current code is:

```
<?php

require 'instagram.class.php';
$instagram = new Instagram('my app id');

$tag = 'winter';

$media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);
$limit = 10;

$size = '150';

foreach(array_slice($media->data, 0, $limit) as $data)
{
echo '<img src="'.$data->images->thumbnail->url.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'">';
}

?>
```

So I want to get the pictures from #winter and #summer also, does have anyone some ideas? (I tried with array but doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible from what I can discern. But to accomplish what I think you're looking for you'd need to fire off two requests and depending on what you want you might want to display the intersecting images or the symmetric difference of the two requests.